# Conditional CSS for all versions of Safari either for OS x or Windows

Tags: css, safari

Could you please help me to add a conditional css for all version of Safari.

I have used this but that only works for windows safari 5.1.7 but it doesnt work with OSx Safari 7.0.3

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari only override */
    ::i-block-chrome,.extraheight {
        height: 180px !important;
    } 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Safari-only css seems like a workaround...

Comment: You should present the problem, because there might be a possible crossbrowser solution, rather than using workarounds.

Comment: listen to @easwee. However, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/2387772

Comment: Yes that only the way I am trying to find that the above conditional css rule is not working for Safari 7.0.3.. any clue?

Comment: It seems that webkit is not detecting.. anyone knows the correct way to implement this conditional css for Safari 7.0.3.. I know this new versions has many css bugs so not sure what to do with it.

Comment: The code you posted worked only for Safari up to version 6.0 (not 6.1 and above)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single one for all versions of Safari, just different versions can be targeted with different types of hacks. This one is the latest, and the product of months of my own research and experimentation:

```
/* Safari 6.1+ (8.0 is the latest version of Safari at this time) */

@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { @media
{
    .safari_only { 

        color:#0000FF; 
        background-color:#CCCCCC; 

    }
}}
```

If you want to test it live (and many others I have been working on for different browsers) check my live test page at: http://browserstrangeness.github.io/css_hacks.html#safari

or mirror at:

http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html#safari